# Standard assumed unit for capacitance

Tags: schematics

I am trying to build a circuit from a schematic where capacitance units are not defined.  The diagram shows a non-polar capacitor with 0.01, and another with 0.001. What should I assume for units? uF pF nF F or something else? If I have to guess I will guess uF, since most of my capacitors are labeled in uF.  I feel like this is a really dumb question, sorry about that.  I did try to find an answer on my own, though.

The diagram is the following:

[image]

Comment: Note this schematic does not adhere to any drawing standards like 10P should be 10p or 10pF and 0.01 units can be left out if stated in Notes to be \$\mu F \$ unless otherwise noted.  Beware of rookie drawings that leave out a lot of details like part numbers or Ref Des. to a parts list

Answer (score 4):

For 0.01 and 0.001, I'd assume uF. For 18, 120, 560, I'd probably assume pF, unless marked as polarised - then it would be uF.  Context would help set the range - in frequency-dependent RF circuits, whole number values would almost certainly be pF, while they would be uF (and polarised) in a power supply.

Comment: Wild, thanks a lot! Sorry I had to ask such a basic question, I probably should have already known.

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly uF for the 0.01 value.

An analysis of the circuit suggests what a sensible value is for the mystery capacitor.

The BC548 transistor is listed as having B = 100 min and 800 max.  Assuming B = 450 (right in the middle)  the input impedance into the base is 455 * 47 ohms =  21.4K.

Combining the 21.4K input impedance in parallel with the other biasing capacitors on the base gives a total impedance of about 2.05K.

Combining 2.05K with the 10nF capacitor gives a low pass filter with a cutoff frequency of about 7.7kHz.

Given that your input comes from a microphone 7.7kHz is a reasonable bandwidth since it is adequate for most voice communications.

If the units on the capacitor had been mF or F the cutoff frequency of the filter would have been way too low to be useful.  If the units had been nF then the cutoff would have been too high (7.7MHz is way beyond the useful range of a typical microphone).  If the units had been pF the capacitor would be impossible to buy since I have never seen capacitors for sale that were in the femto-farad range.

Comment: Down in the pF range it's already very easy to end up with more capacitance in your PCB than in your capacitors. fF capacitors just don't make sense as discrete components.